# Angular Forms Patch Value With Different Field Name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to patch a form with slightly different field name. Is this possible in Angular?
Example: suppose this is my `student.ts` class.

```js
export class Student {
   id: number;
   BIValueTerm: number;
}
```

I want to patch my formgroup with a student object. my formgroup looks like this:

```js
// const student = ... ; student object

const studentForm = new FormGroup({
   id: new FormControl(''),
   bivalueTerm: new FormControl('')
});

studentForm.patchValue(student);
```

now the problem is, `studentForm` properly patches the `id` field but not `bivalueTerm` field. Is there any way I can also patch it?

Comment: problem is with exported class "Student". Make sure key "bivalueTerm" is the same as "BIValueTerm". Either use "bivalueTerm" in Student class or "BIValueTerm" as from element then only it will assign properly

Comment: or else you can use studentForm.patchValue({id: student.id, bivalueTerm: student. BIValueTerm})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way to do get an appropriate result is 
solution 1:

```
export class Student {
   id: number;
   bivalueTerm: number;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
studentForm.patchValue(
  {
   id: student.id, 
   bivalueTerm: student.BIValueTerm
  }
)
```

Comment: yes, both the approaches would work, but that doesn't answer my question. I want to know if I can patch it by changing Patch configuration such that the keys are matched case insensitively.

Comment: No to my knowledge, it is not possible.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, as I found it no other way other than you mentioned.